# Firebase function doesnt update, function returned undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im trying with this firebase function to update the author.

```
 exports.updateCourseName = functions.firestore
    .document('courses/{courseId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data().name;
      const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
      const course1Id = context.params.courseId;
     
      if(newValue != previousValue){

        admin
        .firestore().collection("set").where("course.id", "==", course1Id)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
         //       doc.data().author = newValue
                querySnapshot.docs[0].course
                .update({author : newValue
                })
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error changing Author name in courses", error);
        });
      }
    })
```

I dont get an error in the Logs but   `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate a Cloud Function when all the asynchronous work is completed, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). In the case of a background triggered Cloud Function (e.g. Cloud Firestore function `onUpdate` trigger) you must return the **entire** [chain of promises](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) returned by the asynchronous method calls.

```
exports.updateCourseName = functions.firestore
    .document('courses/{courseId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data().name;
      const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
      const course1Id = context.params.courseId;
     
      if(newValue != previousValue){

        return admin   // <== See the return here
        .firestore().collection("set").where("course.id", "==", course1Id)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
         //       doc.data().author = newValue
                return querySnapshot.docs[0].course  // <== See the return here AND see below
                .update({author : newValue
                })
          } else  {
               return null;   // <== See here: we indicate to the CF that it can be cleaned up
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error changing Author name in courses", error);
            return null;
        });
      } else  {
        return null;   // <== See here: we indicate to the CF that it can be cleaned up
      }
    });
```

---

HOWEVER, it is not clear to me what you want to do with:

```
querySnapshot.docs[0].course.update({author : newValue})
```

What is exactly `course`? The `update()` method is a method of a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html).

You probably want to do

```
querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({author : newValue})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty damn explicit, there: `Function returned UNDEFINED, expected Promise or value`.

The incomplete code fragment you show DOESN'T RETURN ANYTHING. Try:

```
return admin
     .firestore().collection("set").where("course.id", "==", course1Id)
...etc, etc...
```