# Firebase function onUpdate doesnt update another document "Cannot read property 'update' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

this is my code:

```
  exports.updateCourseName = functions.firestore
    .document('courses/{courseId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data().name;
      const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
      const course1Id = context.params.courseId;
      if(newValue != previousValue){
        console.log("veränderung!")
        return admin.firestore().collection("sets").where("course.id", "==", course1Id)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                querySnapshot.docs[0].course.update({name: newValue})
          }
        })
      }
    });
```

This my firebase structure:
[image: courses]
[image: sets]

The code is running with the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`
. But after i change the name in the "courses" ( here is the name "dergerat", the name doesnt change in the sets/{set_id}/course/name. I get the log "veränderung!" after changing the name so this part is working fine.
Is there some problem with the return part? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
querySnapshot.docs[0].course.update({author : newValue})
```

cannot work.

With `querySnapshot.docs[0]` you get a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) and there is no `course` property for this object. The `update()` method is a method of a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) so you should do something along the following lines:

```
exports.updateCourseName = functions.firestore
    .document('courses/{courseId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data().name;
        const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
        const course1Id = context.params.courseId;
        if (newValue != previousValue) {
            console.log("veränderung!")
            return admin.firestore().collection("sets").where("course.id", "==", course1Id)
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({ "course.name": newValue })
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
        } else {
          return null;
        }
    });
```

We make the assumption there is only one doc returned by the query, so we can use `docs[0]` to get the [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) corresponding to the `set` doc. We then use the `ref` property of the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` and we update [the field in the nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

---

PS: See also the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68053976/3371862) to your previous question and the importance to return, in your Cloud Function, the promise returned by the `update()` method.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with Document References there. You can try the following code:

```
exports.updateCourseName = functions.firestore
.document('courses/{courseId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const newValue = change.after.data().name;
  const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
  const course1Id = context.params.courseId;
  if(newValue != previousValue){
    console.log("veränderung!")
    const setsRef = admin.firestore().collection("sets").where("course.id", "==", course1Id)
    return setsRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) return null
      const setId = querySnapshot[0].id
      return admin.firestore().collection("sets").doc(setId).update({"course.name": newValue}).then(() => {
          console.log("Data updated")
          return null
      })
    })
  }
});
```

After the query you can easily get ID of the set (or sets). If there are multiple sets which may contain the same set ID, you may have to use [Batch Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). The code above will only update the course name but you can update other fields similarly.